# Silicone gel "Strataderm" or plant extracts cream "Cicatrix" effect against scars?

Tags: topical-cream-gel, scar-tissue-scars, plastic-surgery, self-healing-repairing

The question is about remedies to minimize scarring. Mostly, two medicines are advised, these being the silicone gel “**Strataderm**” and a cream with extracts of Centella Asiatica and Pine (pinus sylvestris) – “**Cicatrix**”.

Strataderm gel consists of silicone, while Cicatrix cream is composed of plant extracts. Also, these medicines differ in the way they are applied. Strataderm should be applied with a thin layer and left to dry. Cicatrix should be rubbed in by massaging movements.

---

Which remedy is more effective in minimizing scarring? Which of these medications is more likely to show the best effect against scars. The one that based on silicone or the one that based on plant extracts. And is there any sense in combining both these remedies for minimization of scars?